# Swapping adjacent elements of linked list

Tags: c++

The below is my code to recursive swap the adjacent elements of a linked list. I am losing the pointer to every second element after the swap.
The input is 1->2->3->4->5->6->7, I expected the output 2->1->4->3->6->5->7,
but my output is 1->3->5->7.

```
void nodelist::swap(node* head)
{

    node* temp = head->next;
    if (head->next!= nullptr)
    {
        node* temp2 = temp->next;
        temp->next = head;
        head->next = temp2;
        head = head->next; 
        temp = nullptr;
        temp2 = nullptr;
        swap(head);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: Line 3 doesn't do anything as you then imediatly overwrite the entire object.

Comment: @roshvarg Is it your second attempt to get an answer?:)

Comment: No sir I am new to programming and stackoverflow.

Comment: if you have nodes A,B,C, and swap B<->C, A needs to be updated to now point to C. therefore, swapping including head, and swapping later nodes needs to be handled differently

Comment: this problem would be way simpler, if you considered using a sentry node, and doubly linked list.

Comment: @roshvarg also post definition of `node` linked list's struct

Comment: You are passing a pointer to the first node to your function an expecting it to become a pointet to the second node when the function returns. C functions don't work this way. It's a pass by value language.

Comment: @sp2danny As far as I understand the question a list (A,B,C) should become (B,A,C), not (A,C,B). And the head can (and should) be handled exactly same way as every other `next` link in the list—just use `(node**)` as an input type.

Comment: I sincerely hope a  `nodelist` already *has* a member var for its `head`, so I'm somewhat perplexed what the parameter `head` is even for?

Comment: @CiaPan A wasn't necessarily the first node, the example was just to show that when head is changed, you need double pointer, when later nodes are changed, you need previous node

Comment: @sp2danny My point is you don't need a previous node, you just need a reference (or a pointer) to *a pointer* pointing to the current node. And that can be either a `next` in the previous node or a standalone `head_ptr` variable, thus same code for all steps.

Comment: @CiaPan that would work

Answer (score 1):

With no recursion:

```
void swap(node **head)
{
    while (*head && (*head)->next)
    {
        node* tmp = *head;
        *head = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = (*head)->next;
        (*head)->next = tmp;
        head = &tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Invoke `swap( & list_head_ptr)`.

---

Alternatively, you can pass the head pointer by reference-to-pointer and utilize a local pointer-to-pointer member:

```
void swap(node*& head)
{
    node **pp = &head;
    while (*pp && (*pp)->next)
    {
        node* tmp = *pp;
        *pp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = (*pp)->next;
        (*pp)->next = tmp;
        pp = &tmp->next;
    }
}
```

and invoke as `swap(list_head_ptr)`. Either method works.

Comment: @CiaPan thank you but as sp2danny pointed out the solution did not compile.

Comment: @roshvarg you may want to try that again. check the code update.

Comment: @roshvarg i was just a simple bug. Glad it works. I *strongly* advise setting up a short list and walking through it step by step with a debugger to understand what is going on. the premise is simple enough, though the pointer juggle can get a little daunting until you're more comfortable with them.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it is enough to swap only the data members of nodes. There is no need to swap the pointers themselves.

Nevertheless if to use your approach then the function can look like

```
void SwapList( node *head )
{
    if ( head != nullptr && head->next != nullptr )
    {
        node *next = head->next;
        std::swap( *head, *next );
        std::swap( head->next, next->next );

        SwapList( head->next->next );
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct node
{
    int value;
    node *next;
};

node * AddNode( node *head, int value )
{
    head = new node { value, head };

    return head;
}

void PrintList( node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != nullptr; head = head->next )
    {
        std::cout << head->value << ' ';
    }
}

void SwapList( node *head )
{
    if ( head != nullptr && head->next != nullptr )
    {
        node *next = head->next;
        std::swap( *head, *next );
        std::swap( head->next, next->next );

        SwapList( head->next->next );
    }
}

int main() 
{
    node *head = nullptr;

    for ( int i = 10; i != 0; )
    {
        head = AddNode( head, --i );
    }

    PrintList( head );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    SwapList( head );

    PrintList( head );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 0 3 2 5 4 7 6 9 8
```

You can use the shown function as a template (or base) for your function.

Comment: Isn't *avoiding* swapping node guts at the value-level somewhat the point of linked list pointer management? I.e shouldn't the goal be to simply diddle with the *pointers* in the first place, leaving the rest of the node structure intact and unaffected (i.e. the `value`)?

Comment: @WhozCraig The approach you have pointed out also can be used.

Comment: you first swap the whole thing, ie `value` and `next` and then swap back just `next`. why not just swap `value`

Comment: @ sp2danny The problem is that I do not know how he defined the node.:) So my approach does not depend on implementation of the node. By the way I have written in my post that it is enough to swap only data members.:)

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion:

```
void nodelist::swap(node** head) {
  if (!*head || !(*head)->next) return;
  node* const sw = (*head)->next;
  (*head)->next = sw->next;
  sw->next = *head;
  *head = sw;
  swap(&(sw->next->next));
}
```

Comment: how does `sw->next = *head;` even *compile* when `sw` is a pointer to const ? (or did I read that wrong) ?

Comment: const prefer to bind to the left, so its a const pointer to node

Comment: @sp2danny yeah. I did in fact read it wrong. Initially I though it was node const *, not node * const. Thanks for the clarification. danka.

Answer (score 0):

If `head` is the pointer which stores the address of `firstNode (value=1)`, then try following function:

```
void nodelist::swap(node* head){
    node* temp = head->next; //head->next is first-node which needs to switch with it's next node
    if (temp!= nullptr && temp->next!=nullptr){
        head->next=temp->next;  //move second node to first
        temp->next = head->next->next; //put second's next in first's
        head->next->next = temp; //and first will be second's next
        temp = nullptr; // swaping done
        swap(head->next->next); //do it for next couple
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1cc0d02b5599da4

OR

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1e200b687825d80

If `head` itself is the `firstNode (value=1)`, then passing `head` by value will not work, either you need to pass it by address/reference **OR** do it like in following link:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1e200b687825d80

Comment: @sp2danny: according to your link, I checked the `struct node`. In that case my first solution will work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1cc0d02b5599da4 | that's why I asked from OP to show struct-refer comment on question. || Note: if you want to start swapping from first node then store `node * ptr2head=new node{0,head}` and pass ptr2head in swap function.

Comment: @sp2danny: like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1e200b687825d80  || THANKS for pointing problem in second one, but my first one was working, and also thanks for giving me link of that useful site to test c++ code... :) That's the power of stack-overflow community to increase the quality, efficiency of answers...  (y)